# Graphics get cropped when wrapped in Hyperlink and Inset in MMA 12.2 (doesn't seem to happen on 12.1 RPi) Bug?

Tags: graphics, bugs, hyperlink, inset

I've noticed that wrapping a `Graphic[]` in `Hyperlink[]` causes weird things to happen when using `Inset[]` (which, in my case, is being automatically used by `GraphicsGrid[]` and `Text[]`). Here's a minimal-ish example where you great a white rectangle with a red border and a number in the middle. You then `Inset[]` that into some arbitrary position and, this is the important part, specify the new size.

If the `Graphics[]` object is embedded as-is, it works fine. If you instead try to embed `Hyperlink[g]`, it just renders *wrong*. It's all cutoff.

```
g = Graphics[{White, EdgeForm[{Red, Thickness[Large]}], 
    Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}], Inset[Style[1, Black, Bold]]}];
Inset[g, {1620, -180}, ImageScaled[{0.5`, 0.5`}], {360, 360}] // 
  Graphics;
Inset[Hyperlink[g, None], {1620, -180}, 
   ImageScaled[{0.5`, 0.5`}], {360, 360}] // Graphics;
{%%%, %%, %}
```

[image: Output I get from the example code]

The first image is the Graphics object itself, the second is the Inset[] results with just the graphics obejct, and the third is if I Hyperlink the graphics object. If I resize the Hyperlink-ed result enough, it eventually shows the border:

[image]

So I think what's happening is that the Hyperlink wrapper is causing the Graphics object to end up cropped, not scaled.

Can someone please see if they can reproduce this issue? If so, I'll try to report it as a bug.

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! I've reproduced it, and I'm not sure why this is happening, but just wanted to mention a possible workaround: wrap `HyperLink` around the `Inset` instead of on the inside. To accomplish this without access to the explicit `Inset`, you could potentially define a wrapper `innerlink` with the following upvalue: `Inset[innerlink[x_, y_], z___] ^:= Hyperlink[Inset[x, z], y]`. Not sure if this works in general, though.

Comment: I tried that, unfortunately, `Hyperlink[Inset[...]]` produces a result in the exported PDF (I'm tyring to make a programmatic hyperlinked PDF year planner, so this is used to hyperlink from the date in a month calendar to that day's page later in the PDF) that doesn't work. No idea _why_ it doesn't work, one would imagine that hyperlinking a higher level object should work _better_, but alas, here we are.

Thanks for testing and confirming it isn't just me! I'll file a bug and update here accordingly if I get any response.

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed as of 12.3.1! The behaviour is now as expected.

[image: All of the three considered layouts now behave as expected]